# PHP TCP Socket caches the file itself

Tags: php

I've made a PHP TCP Socket server and it seems I can't change the file at all, while I am able to edit and save it on the server.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://IPADDRESS:25000", $errno, $errstr);

if (!$socket) {
    die("$errstr ($errno)\n");
}

... the rest of the code ...

fclose($socket);

?>
```

The first time I've executed the script, it listened as expected. I've changed the port and refreshed the PHP script but I still get an error that indicates that the `Address already in use` (and shows the old 25000 port number instead of the new one).

I tried to `kill -9` the process that keeps port 25000 open (with success), but still no luck. I refresh the script and get tha same error regarding the same old port.

The new port isn't listening at all by the way.

**EDIT - netstat output asked  in the comments**

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name     Timer
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2086            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1718/cpsrvd (SSL) -  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2087            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1718/cpsrvd (SSL) -  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2277/cpdavd - accep  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23410/exim           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2091            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2277/cpdavd - accep  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23373/dovecot        off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:783           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13367/perl           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23373/dovecot        off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16467/rpcbind        off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2095            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1718/cpsrvd (SSL) -  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11435/nginx: logger  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2096            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1718/cpsrvd (SSL) -  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10310/httpd          off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23410/exim           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23089/pdns_server    off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23110/sshd           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8087            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25794/monitorix-htt  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23410/exim           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23089/pdns_server    off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11435/nginx: logger  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:444             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10310/httpd          off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2077            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2277/cpdavd - accep  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2078            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2277/cpdavd - accep  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2079            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2277/cpdavd - accep  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2277/cpdavd - accep  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23373/dovecot        off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2082            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1718/cpsrvd (SSL) -  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23373/dovecot        off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2083            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1718/cpsrvd (SSL) -  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      23150/mysqld         off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      23410/exim           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      23373/dovecot        off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:783                 :::*                    LISTEN      13367/perl           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      23373/dovecot        off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      16467/rpcbind        off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11435/nginx: logger  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::81                   :::*                    LISTEN      10310/httpd          off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      23410/exim           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      23089/pdns_server    off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      23110/sshd           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      23410/exim           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      11435/nginx: logger  off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::444                  :::*                    LISTEN      10310/httpd          off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      23373/dovecot        off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      23373/dovecot        off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           23089/pdns_server    off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           16467/rpcbind        off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           6891/chronyd         off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:954             0.0.0.0:*                           16467/rpcbind        off (0.00/0/0)
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                23089/pdns_server    off (0.00/0/0)
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                16467/rpcbind        off (0.00/0/0)
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                6891/chronyd         off (0.00/0/0)
udp6       0      0 :::954                  :::*                                16467/rpcbind        off (0.00/0/0)
```

Comment: `netstat -tulnop` (Linux) or `netstat -ano` (Windows) and check which PID it is attached to

Comment: @Jaquarh there is no listening port 25000, since I killed it manually. No open php-fpm processes for that port. Double checked.

Comment: And the port you're trying to change it to, is there anything already listening on there?

Comment: @Jaquarh nothing listening on there. Both ports are down.

Comment: Can you show the output of the `netstat` command (update the question) - execute it with root permissions

Comment: if you `ps -aef --forest | grep php` do you see anything running? How are you executing this script? Is there multiple calls to the execution or socket binding? The address is not in use according to your results. Since you have `python`, you can verify so by doing `python3 -m http.server 25000` - you should see it works fine. It appears like you're trying to bind the socket atleast twice.

Comment: @Jaquarh answered my question below. I don't know why this worked but it did.

Comment: I assume `stream_socket_server` creates a symlink resource as reference to the port status which is being cached by PHP. Glad you resolved your issue

Answer (score 0):

I've found a PHP function called `clearstatcache()` which for some reason seems to be working. I called that function before anything else in my script and it's now updated as it should.

Anyone that can explain it to me?